# Multilingual site using MSM?

Tags: ee2

I'm about to begin a couple of multilingual websites using EE. I've been researching options and thought that MSM might be the best option as I'm able to have language specific URLs and a way to simplify site updates by multiple authors.

I have not used MSM and am struggling to get it setup locally. I've got it running, but how do I create the URL's to the second domain locally. I really would love to have the address be local.domain.com/en for the default site and local.domain.com/fr for the secondary site. Is this done in MAMP Pro?

Second issue... I really want to continue using the Focus Lab Master Config, but I'm finding it confusing to setup with MSM.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MAMP Pro will allow you to setup "custom" URLs for your local environment for each of the sites. I have mine on a separate laptop and then use a local IP Number (instead of local.domain.com) to access the laptop like a web server. Regular MAMP doesn't make this easy. So a local IP number would then give you access to "en" and "fr" as follows...

`192.168.0.2/fr`

192.168.0.2/en

(stack exchange won't let me post numeric IP numbers here so I'm afraid you'll have to figure that out)

But MAMP pro has to be setup for that.

As mentioned by Mark Jr. for the MSM setup you would have two directories setup in MAMP, one for en and one for fr. The setup for the main one include the Exp Eng system directory and the cloned/copied site has its own directory that is essentially the same as the first but without the system directory. Then you use the admin.php and the index.php in the cloned directory to "communicate" with the Exp Eng system in the other directory. That's why you need to make sure you install and setup MSM as explained in the Exp Eng official documentation.

Comment: That actually helps a lot. I wasn't sure if I had to setup to domaines with MAMP Pro. I was trying to do it with 1 address. Have you had any experience using MSM and Focus Lab Master Config?

Comment: Mark, I've not used Focus Lab Master Config myself so I can't supply any info on that. - Bob

Answer (score 1):

For your first issue you simply need to create a new folder say "es". In that es folder you copy over your admin.php (or whatever you renamed it to) and your index.php file and update the paths. You'll also need to uncomment the bits about MSM as well. Have you looked at the MSM docs located here?

http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/sites/

The documentation is pretty good but if you still need assistance please make sure you have followed their instructions first and post any relevant issues you are having and we'll get you squared away!

Comment: Thanks Mark, I'm going to take a closer look on Monday. I'll write back shortly. Thanks

Comment: Sounds good and hope you get it all worked out!